# Graphics failures on both linux and windows

Tags: ubuntu, graphics-card, hardware-failure, arch-linux, nvidia-graphics-card

On windows, if I allow the system turn the monitors off (due to being idle), about once a week, it will fail to resume.  There does not seem to be a pattern to this.

On linux (Arch 64, fully updated running nouveau GPU drivers), the system will crash whenever GNOME is started, usually with a "nouveau failed to idle on channel x" error.

When I try the Nvidia binary driver, my system will arbitrarily freeze.  I've posted about this twice on the arch forums but I never get any responses.

I also tried to install Ubuntu 64 (12.10) but I again received a "failed to idle" error when trying to start the live image.

I'm starting to think that this is a hardware issue but I have no idea how to diagnose it or test the hardware in any meaningful way.  As much as I would like to at this point, trashing everything and rebuilding the system is out of the question for now...

My system:
4gb ram,
Nvidia 9600GSO,
Intel i5 1st gen

If you need more specifics, I'll be glad to dig around.

Comment: I think I read of similar issues with DP port connected monitors and poor quality cables. It is a wild shot, but you could borrow and test with other cables.